# essentially self adjointness of Laplacian with the inverse square singular potential.

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

Let define $H_c: L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to  L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as a densly defined linear operator as follow:
$$ H_c u= \Delta u - \frac{c}{|x|^2} u$$

In reading a paper I encountered to the following theorem

> $H_c$ is essentially self adjoint if and only if $c\leq \frac{n(n-4)}{4}$.

My try:

From a well-known theorem it is enough to show that 
$$ ker((H_c)^* \pm i I) ={0} $$
It means that 
$$ -\Delta u+ \frac{c}{|x|^2}u \pm i u=0 $$
has the trivial solution iff $c \leq \frac{n(n-4)}{4}$.

Comment: What is your question here?  And your "try" doesn't appear to do anything than substitute values?

Comment: Some discussion [here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/the-inverse-cube-force-law/) in the "Quantum" section.